# Why the original html content is modified when it is open by a browser?

Tags: html, dom, browser

I have some HTML content and I need to get the exact XPATH of some elements on the structure, but when the HTML is opened by the Browser the original structure is modified, so I get the XPATH based on Browser's structure and when the original content is going to be processed by my end the XPATH does not work or does not match.

I tried it on Google Chrome and on Firefox and I got the same behavior.

#### Original HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <div>
                <div> <img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0255/4105/products/Classic-Ear-Cuff-Gold_72a095ad-b344-49b6-8b4a-5335304f09bc_160x160_cropped@3x.jpg?v=1548871945" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Ring</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> something </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Browser's HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div> <img src="Result_files/Classic-Ear-Cuff-Gold_72a095ad-b344-49b6-8b4a-5335304f09bc_1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Ring</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> something </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can i prevent this behavior on Browsers? or Are there any known rules why this modifications are being applied?

Comment: If you write valid html you'll have a better chance... (run your html through a validator).

Comment: Excuse me just to clarify. I do not write the HTML, the HTML comes to my app by a previous process and I already run the HTML content through a validator, but this tool does not modify the structure. It only looks for wrong attributes, tags or syntax errors and the result is valid.
I use [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) as node package.

Comment: No, you can't change the browser's behaviour. The known rules are the HTML parsing rules detailed in full in [section 8.2 of the HTML5 specification](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#parsing-html-documents).